# Spotify: Getting metadata without a user logging in

Tags: rest, spotify

I would like to be able to get song metadata (song title, artist name, album title) from Spotify's Restful Web API. I've looked through the Spotify Web API Documentation and played around with their console, but I almost seems like a user needs to login to be able to get the OAuth token or to refresh the token. Is it possible to get song metadata from the Spotify Web API without the user logging in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with the [Client Credentials flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/).